# Dynamic LINQ instead of ExecuteSqlRaw

Tags: sql, linq, dynamic, entity-framework-core, raw

Because I'm going to use Entity Framework Core, I'm trying to convert a SqlRaw statement

```
            var sql = @$"
                         update ItemList
                         set flag = 1
                         where
                             flag = 0 and
                            {groupingField} in (select {groupingField} from ItemList
                                                    where ID in (select itemID from selectedItems))
            ";
            int noOfRowsAffected = DbContext.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql);
```

into a sequence of LINQ statements.

```
            var ids = DbContext.selectedItems
                      .Select(x => x.itemID).ToList();

            var groupIds = DbContext.ItemList
                           .Where(p => ids.Contains(p.Id) && p.flag == 0
                           .Select(p => p.GetType().GetProperty(groupingField).GetValue(p)).ToList();

            var rows = DbContext.ItemList
                .Where(p => groupIds.Contains(p.GetType().GetProperty(groupingField).GetValue(p)))
                .ToList();

            foreach(var row in rows)
            {
                row.flag = 1;
            }
```

When I execute the statments I catch an exception on the third statement (var rows = ...):

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<ItemList>
.Where(t => __groupIds_0.Contains(t.GetType().GetProperty(__groupingField_1).GetValue(t)))' could not be 
translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation 
explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). 
See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

How do I rewrite the statement that it can be translated?

Comment: So, you need just LINQ query and then you will update all loaded entities by yourself? Do you have feeling that you will slowdown this function cardinally?

Comment: I'm aware, that performance will slow down. I didn't mention that I have to use Entity Framework Core. Therfore SqlRaw has to be eliminated.

Comment: `ItemList` has some base class? Because access to `flag` should be generalized too.

Comment: ItemList is a Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<ItemList>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following extension is help to do what you want and even supports `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable` items:

```cs
var ids = DbContext.selectedItems.Select(x => x.itemID);

var rows = DbContext.ItemList
      .FilterByItems(ids, groupingField)
      .Where(p => p.flag == 0)
      .ToList();

foreach (var row in rows)
{
      row.flag = 1;
}
```

And implementation:

```cs
public static class FilterExtensions
{
      public static IQueryable<TEntity> FilterByItems<TEntity, TKey>(this IQueryable<TEntity> query,
            IEnumerable<TKey> items, Expression<Func<TEntity, TKey>> entityKey)
      {
            var entityParam = entityKey.Parameters[0];

            if (items is IQueryable queryableItems)
            {
                  var containsLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(
                        Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), nameof(Queryable.Contains),
                              new[] {typeof(TKey)},
                              queryableItems.Expression,
                              entityKey.Body
                        ),
                        entityParam);
                  return query.Where(containsLambda);
            }
            else
            {
                  var containsLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(
                        Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), nameof(Enumerable.Contains),
                              new[] {typeof(TKey)},
                              Expression.Constant(items),
                              entityKey.Body
                        ),
                        entityParam);
                  return query.Where(containsLambda);
            }
      }

      public static IQueryable<TEntity> FilterByItems<TEntity, TKey>(this IQueryable<TEntity> query,
            IEnumerable<TKey> items, string entityKey)
      {
            var entityParam     = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "e");
            var entityKeyLambda =
                  Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, TKey>>(Expression.PropertyOrField(entityParam, entityKey), entityParam);

            return query.FilterByItems(items, entityKeyLambda);
      }
}
```

Comment: That works great. Thank you. The only tthing I had to change, was to force the type to be not nullable by adding "?? 0".  So it's now:

var ids = DbContext.selectedItems.Select(x => x.itemID ?? 0);

Otherwise I caught an exception "Expression of type 'System.Int64' cannot be used for return type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int64]'".